# how to actualise a variable in template?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a `ion-input` with a ngModel. I am trying to print the value of the input with `(input)` event, but, the variable doesn't print the new value immediately. It prints the value when I press some other part of the screen. Do you have any idea of why?

```
 <ion-input type="number" (input)="change()" [(ngModel)]="value"></ion-input>

{{value}}
```

EDIT:

```
value: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

change() {
    console.log('change ' + this.value);
}
```

Comment: what is your change() function? and is value initialized?

Comment: I think `ngModel` alone is enough to print this value to UI. Also, you have used it correctly. Should work. Unless you are doing something with `change()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a change function, just need the ngModel

```
<ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value"></ion-input>

{{value}}
```

with this alone you'be able to update the value variable

Comment: This is a strange behavior, for me with the (input) it acts like your problem, i can only see the new value if it loses the focus. Can you post more of your code? maybe your entire page and this page .ts file

Comment: it's very strange, I have tested a lot, but I still have this behavior. I edited my post with my Typescript code. Very simple. The console.log give the correct value inmediately, but the template is updated only if I click somewhere else in the screen...